# Can I get back an image that displayed momentarily in the camera finder?

Tags: file-system, camera, media-files, temp-files

I had someone take a photo for me with my phone.  I didn't verify the photo but I took the phone back and put it into sleep (pushed the power button to turn the screen off without switching off the power) with the camera app still open.

Some hours later when I woke the phone up, the camera app displayed and in the finder there was for a split second the image that the person had taken for me.  The finder then switched to what was currently in front of the lens.

The photo doesn't seem to be saved.  It's not in the folder where photos normally end up.  However since the image did show up in the finder for that split second well after the fact, the phone must have saved it somewhere at least temporarily.

I've seen this phenomenon before, on multiple phones.  In this kind of case, might the image still be somewhere that I could retrieve it, and if so where?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean but you can check in `Phone Storage > Pictures > .thumbnail` folder. It will be a hidden folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the preserved image you saw after unlocking the phone was still saved somewhere in RAM by the graphic driver.

Waking up the camera takes a few milliseconds so you could see the old image in RAM before it was overwritten by the new live image from the camera.

Thus I don't see a chance to recover that image as it had not been saved to flash storage.